# How to remove border next to v-navigation-drawer

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

I made a navigation drawer WITHOUT borders but a thin line on the left just can't seem to go away.
I tried doing a `border : none` to remove any border around the component, it won't work.

I also tried inspecting the element, and the problem is a `<div class="v-navigation-drawer__border"></div>` so I tried removing it by calling it in the CSS but it's still there. I even added the !important propriety.

Does anyone know how to remove a border next to a v-navigation-border ?
[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK4xu.png)

Comment: Can you share some of your code or replicate de issue in a codesanbox? You can use this vuetify template I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-obbqe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) for scoped CSS to select inner elements of components.

```html
<style scoped>
.v-navigation-drawer >>> .v-navigation-drawer__border {
  display: none
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

From [docs v3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props-floating)([v2](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props)).

```
A floating drawer has no visible container (no border-right)
```

So, you can just pass `floating` to your drawer.

Answer (score 0):

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#sass-navigation-drawer-border-width

According to the vuetify doc, you could set the variable `#$navigation-drawer-border-width` to `0`

```
$navigation-drawer-border-width: 0
```